# How can I get actual corners point of UIImageView after applying rotation transform

Tags: ios, image-rotation

I've applied the rotation transform on the `UIImageImage`

Suppose the actual frame of UIImageView is

```
Frame : (100.0, 360.0, 200.0, 130)
```

The white border is the frame

[image]

After applying rotation to some degrees the `UIImageView` returning frame is

```
Frame After Rotation : (97.10, 310.81, 219.79, 240.37)
```

[image]

What I need to get is the actual corners points of the rotated image.

[image]

Please help. I'm not sure how to get the actual corners points

As per answer by @sandeep, the result is as follows

[image]

The dots should move by the corner of the image and should stick to the corners. I Know if I place the dots as subview of UIImageView but Dots are free and can not place inside `UIImageView` to move when rotation applying.

Answer (score 2):

You would get the points from each corner of the original frame and pass them through the same transform.

So the upper left corner would be `let ul = view.frame.origin` before the rotation.

Then the point after rotation is `let ulT = ul.applying(view.transform)`

Example:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    var imageView: UIView!
    var rotationRecognizer: UIRotationGestureRecognizer!
    var cornerView: UIView!

    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        let frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 200, width: 200, height: 200)
        imageView = UIView(frame: frame)
        imageView.backgroundColor = .blue
        view.addSubview(imageView)

        cornerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 95, y: 195, width: 10, height: 10))
        cornerView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        cornerView.backgroundColor = .red
        view.addSubview(cornerView)

        rotationRecognizer = UIRotationGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleRotation(recognizer:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(rotationRecognizer)

        self.view = view
    }

    @objc func handleRotation(recognizer: UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {
         imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: recognizer.rotation)
        var cornerPoint = CGPoint(
            x: 100 - imageView.center.x,
            y: 200 - imageView.center.y
        )
        cornerPoint = cornerPoint.applying(imageView.transform)
        cornerPoint.x += imageView.center.x
        cornerPoint.y += imageView.center.y
        cornerView.center = cornerPoint
    }
}

// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

Comment: Thanks to answer @Ken but the transformation only applies to the `CGPoint`. I've updated my question. Please check. I need to rotate the dots with the rotation on `UIImageView`

Comment: That's correct. So, you would need to offset the point based on the rotation point in the image (looks like you intend to rotate around the center). Then you can use that transformed point as the center point of your corner image.

Comment: @AmitSingh I added code example to make it more clear.